# Efficient way to find a sub string in postgress

Tags: sql, substring, sql-like

I have a column that has very long test in it and I want to find if there are word(variable) in it. The example words I want to find are

`P${qwe}` , `P ${qwe}` , `PHP${qwe}` , `PHP ${qwe}`

I have tried doing

`like '%P${%'`

but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How do you mean "efficient"? Less code? Faster execution time?

Comment: @AndyLester yes less code ; faster .. as i would do 1 query for each data i need to find is there a way i can do it in one query all together ?

Comment: PostgreSQL allows the use of regular expressions for conditions, see [Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html).